# Create Excel bar chart from a data source in C# code instead of a spreadsheet range using Aspose.Cells

Tags: c#, excel, aspose-cells

I'm trying to use Aspose.Cells to generate a bar chart on a spreadsheet. The data source is an IEnumerable of decimal numbers, which are retrieved from a database. Reading the Aspose.Cells documentation, the only way I've seen to create a bar chart in code is by taking the bar chart's data from a range on a spreadsheet. I want to generate the chart directly from the IEnumerable, without having to actually include the data on a spreadsheet. Is there any way to do this, either using Aspose.Cells or standard .NET libraries? If it's possible to generate a temporary workbook in code, paste the data onto it and use that as a data source (discarding it immediately afterward), I could probably also make that work. Thanks!

Comment: If your chart is creatable in Microsoft Excel, then it will also be creatable with Aspose.Cells. You should create your desired chart manually using Microsoft Excel and provide it to us. We will load your provided Excel file, observe the Chart’s various properties in Debug or Quick Watch windows and provide you Aspose.Cells sample code that will create the similar chart. Therefore, please provide us your expected or desired chart and we will provide you Aspose.Cells sample code. Thanks. ---- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: Is my explanation of the problem not enough? It’s pretty simple what I’m asking. I just want to create a standard bar chart. I don’t see how actually seeing the chart would be helpful beyond that. Can you create a chart with Aspose.Cells without sourcing the data from an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks. We will share the sample code and its output Chart with you for your inspection. It will be a simple Bar Chart and it will have Direct Values inside it. Means, there will be no value inside the Excel worksheet. Excel worksheet will only have chart and nothing else. Hopefully, it will fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following code. It creates the **Bar Chart** using Aspose.Cells APIs. Please read the comments inside the code for more help.

The following screenshot shows the output Excel file containing the Bar Chart generated by the code for your reference.

[image: Bar Chart generated by Aspose.Cells]

---

**Sample Code in C#**

```
// Create empty workbook.
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

// Access first worksheet.
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

// Add Bar chart in first worksheet.
int idx = ws.Charts.Add(ChartType.Bar, 5, 2, 20, 10);

// Access Bar chart.
Chart ch = ws.Charts[0];

// Add two number series, true means they are vertical.
ch.NSeries.Add("{6,3,1,7}", true);
ch.NSeries.Add("{2,5,7,1}", true);

// Set the category data to show on X-axis.
ch.NSeries.CategoryData = "{Apple,Pear,Orange,Mango}";

// Set the name of first and second series.
ch.NSeries[0].Name = "Cricket";
ch.NSeries[1].Name = "Hockey";

// Save the output in xlsx format.
wb.Save("outputBarChart.xlsx", SaveFormat.Xlsx);
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose